# Max cell size: cannot change the size,

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I have the following mesh

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]



 bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{15, 10}, {5, 10}, {5, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1200}, {5,
       1200}, {5, 1190}, {15, 1190}, {15, 10}, {1485, 10}, {1485, 
      1190}, {15, 1190}, {1485, 10}, {1495, 10}, {1495, 0}, {1500, 
      0}, {1500, 1200}, {1495, 1200}, {1495, 1190}, {1485, 
      1190}, {1496, 1170}, {1499, 1170}, {1499, 1180}, {1496, 
      1180}, {1, 20}, {4, 20}, {4, 30}, {1, 30}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 
        9}, {13, 14}, {14, 15}, {15, 16}, {16, 17}, {17, 18}, {18, 
        19}, {19, 20}, {21, 22}, {22, 23}, {23, 24}, {24, 21}, {25, 
        26}, {26, 27}, {27, 28}, {28, 25}}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
       2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5}]}, 
   "RegionHoles" -> {{1498, 1175}, {2, 25}},"MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 200];


mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh["Wireframe"] (*This works*)
```

However, when I try to change the mesh cell size I cannot, Kernel quits itself: such as

```
   mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> .02];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

I want to set maximum cell measure on the boundaries: is there something I am missing?

so, it works, if I divide every length by 1000, why it is not working the way it is? However, at the boundaries, I still can not change the cell size?

=================================================================

With `ToBoundaryMesh[region, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 200]`

and

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 3000];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

I get,

[image]

Why does it look uneven at the boundaries (I mean at the two standing sides where the cells are finer but in the middle, they seem less fine "marked regions"), "is there a way to check if it is fine or not"?

Comment: I might get a ban for this comment, but I cannot resist...size matters!

Comment: Not sure if you have already seen the tutorial on [ElementMesh generation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html). This provides a good introduction to finite element mesh generation in the WL.

Comment: @user21 I am dealing with the linear boundary representation and I have been following the ElementMesh generation, so I am not sure if "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" is still being ignore or not, because I am not able to find any example.

Comment: @MuhammadAli, I have tried to clarify that in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.02` you are producing an *extremely* fine mesh. Here is a `MaxCellMeasure -> 100`

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 100];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

You'd probably want to do something like this:

```
ToBoundaryMesh[region, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> xzy]
```

but for this to work, you'd need a symbolic region description or a manual boundary mesh that resolves the boundary to the size you want. I guess a symbolic region is a bit easier.

Note that "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" works for symbolic regions, like

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[Disk[], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.025];
ToElementMesh[bmesh]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

but not for manual boundary meshes like:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 0.2}, {1., 1.}, {0., 
      1.}, {0., 0.22}, {0.3, 0.22}, {0.3, 0.2}, {0., 0.2}},
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 1}, {3, 8}}]}
   , "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.001];
ToElementMesh[bmesh]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, I am not able to change the cell sizes at boundaries, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" does nothing,  I going through this example though, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141386/making-good-meshes.

Comment: @MuhammadAli, please see the second part of my answer. Also, note that in your post you do not make use of "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" .

Comment: Thanks! I just updated the output with the commands.